# Unique constraint violations on concurrent insert in EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, amazon-web-services, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an ETL/data ingestion process for an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application.  The workflow is as follows:

1. CSV is uploaded to Amazon S3
2. Initial lambda function is triggered that "chunks" the csv into
   many small files with 1000 records each.  The reason for this is to
   work around Lambda's 5 minute runtime limit.
3. Each of these "chunk" files trigger another lambda function that
   actually processes the records and inserts/updates the Postgres
   database.  This function uses a *Parallel.ForEach* loop thus
   increasing the concurrency even further.

The data being loaded basically amounts to user data for a business application, but spans several tables.  The problem I'm running in to is that when two users with an identical **new** related entity are imported at essentially the same time, I end up with a unique constraint error because they both fail to find the related entity and attempt to create it, but of course one wins and then the second fails when it also attempts to create it.

I'm familiar with how to deal with concurrency when updating records using row-level locking and the like, but for inserts I'm not sure how best to handle the situation beyond maybe trying to catch the error and then look up the existing entity and attach it to the new user.  In other languages and frameworks I've used CreateOrUpdate sort of functionality to deal with this, but I can't find anything similar in EF Core.

Comment: The first place to do these kind of Bulk-Inserts is the DBMS itself. Moving that to your client will only cause you issues with timeouts and race conditons. Why are you not doing this in the DBMS? Why are you not doing it via a BULK INSERT SQL Command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) or equivalent for your DB of choice?

Comment: @Christopher Mainly because of the amount of transforming of the data that I have to do before insertion.  I suppose I could transform the data, write it back to CSVs, and then use postgres's COPY command (I assume the SQL Server command you linked is similar) to actually insert the data.  I may look in to that if I can't easily solve this problem with the current implementation.

Comment: Have you tried to check row before to insert with a linq query?